# Is there a way in C++ to only return the the last instance of a for loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

Like for example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for (int n=10; n>0; n--){
        cout<< n <<", ";}
}
```

This will output the numbers 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
So is there a new way so I just get the last instance of the loop, the 1?
I new at this and google isn't giving me any answers.

Comment: So you are getting the 1 or not getting it? If you want the last instance, you can put an if statement in the loop...

Comment: do you mean you want to output `1` instead of `10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1` ?

Comment: Yes.
However, I just used an if statement like the other posters suggested.
If there is another way it might be useful for the future.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to detect whether the current iteration of a `for` loop is the last one. But if the behavior of the loop is predictable, you can usually write code that can detect when you're on the last iteration.

In this case, you could do something like:

```
if (n == 1) {
    cout << n << "\n";
}
```

in the body of the loop. (Of course it would be simpler in this case to replace the entire loop with `cout << "1\n";`, but I presume this is an example of something more complex.)

In more complicated cases, you can save whatever information you need in the body of the loop:

```
int value_to_print:
for ( ... ) {
    value_to_print = i;
}
std::cout << value_to_print << "\n";
```

On each iteration, `value_to_print` is replaced by the current value of `i`. The final value is the value of `i` on the last iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a variable (outside the loop) to hold the "current" value of `n`; whatever happens to the loop (exit condition reached, `break`, an exception is thrown...) the value will stay there:

```
int last_n;
for (int n=10; n>0; n--) {
    last_n = n;
    cout<< n <<", ";

    if (something) {
        break;                   // works in this case
    } else if (something else) {
        throw some_random_error; // works in this case too
    }
}

cout << "The last value of 'n' was " << last_n << endl;
```

Comment: ... but be very certain, in this case, that the loop *did* execute at least once.  If it didn't, the value in `last_n` will be unpredictable.  *(read: "garbage")*  This solution is very excellent:  it just has this one "gotcha."  (What I sometimes do in this case is to initialize `last_n` to a "very obviously wrong, *but defined*, value that I know will stand out like a sore thumb:  something like, say, `-1122334455`.  Or, if I am feeling whimsical, `0xDEADBEEF`.  Obviously, it's a dummy-value that's meant to be immediately replaced.  BUT, if the loop never executes, "it stands out!"

Comment: @MikeRobinson: true. On the other hand, initializing `last_n` to something (like the initial value of `n`, so `10` in this case) would still be dangerous: it wouldn't be random garbage, but if the loop isn't executed it would still be wrong. Perhaps even more dangerous, because it would be harder to spot. I think the only way to be certain would be to use a `bool loop_run_at_least_once = false;`, which is set to true inside the loop, when `last_n` is set. But maybe it's a little overkill...

Comment: Absolutely so.  If there's any "legitimate" case where the loop might not execute at all, you *must* be prepared to detect that.  *(As you imply, a good way is to set a `bool` to False before the loop begins, then set it to True within the loop.)* If, at the end of the loop, that flag is still False, then the value of `last_n` is worthless.  (But I, maybe impulsively, maybe anal-retentively(?), still "initialize all variables to *something,* anyway.")

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple if statement for that.

```
int main()
{
    for (int n=10; n>0; n--) {
        cout << n << ", ";
        if( n == 1 ) {
            return n;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to accomplish this is: -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    for (int n = 10; n > 0; n--){
        x = n;
    }
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to programming too and was trying to figure out something which will allow me to get the last instance of my loop as output.
I tried something and got the output, see if it can help you (if there's a mistake please let me know).
Here user input string is being replaced by `"*"` and instead of giving output of every instance i have made so only last instance is given as output.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        string str;
        int string_length;//string length
        cout<<"Enter your Email-ID: ";
        cin>>str;

        string_length = str.length(); //to give the length of input string and use it for the loop
        cout<<"lentgh of the string: "<<string_length <<endl;
        for(int x = 0; x <= string_length; x++){
                str[x] = '*';
            while(x==string_length) //string_length is the last instance of the loop
                {
                    cout<<"Here's your Encrypted Email-ID: " <<str<<endl;
                    break;
                }
        }
    return 0;
}
```